# converting an element of an array to a separate String

Tags: arrays, swift, string, casting, swift3

So I have this problem where I can't convert an element of my array to a string

I have a string like this

`var description:[String] =["blue","yellow","red"]`

and I want to give one element of my array to another variable which is chosen by another integer like this

`var pick:[Int] = 2
var chosen:[String] = description[pick]`

it says Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type '[String]' and to fix it xcode suggests to do it like this

```
var chosen:[String] = [description[pick]]
```

now if I want to cast this variable to another one or give it to a function or whatever it will say Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type '[[String]]' please help.

Comment: Is required for variable chosen to be an array? Otherwise you could just:
var chosen: String = description[pick]

Comment: no you are right thanks.

Comment: I posted it as an answer, please mark it as Answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is required for variable chosen to be an array? 
Otherwise you could just:

```
var chosen: String = description[pick]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting very confused here...

First...

```
var array = ["red", "yellow"]
```

Is an array of strings. Don't call it description. Call things what they are.

Second...

```
var pick: [Int]
```

Is declaring an array. Setting it `= 2` doesn't make sense.

Change your last line to...

```
var chosen: String = array[pick]
```

In the above line using `[String]` here is telling the system that you are getting an array of Strings. You're not. You're getting a String here.

Comment: i was just making an example , like making a integer like carrot or etc but thanks i was just wrong with making chosen an array instead of string and mago helped me realize it thanks anyway.

Comment: @N9va ok. I still don't really know what you're trying to do. There are more problems with your code than just the string array.

Comment: well its in a class which is a object  that has couple of traits and I choose between them and create different entities with int pick and int pick is random but it was not really necessary to type it all here so I just presented the bit that was confusing me.